# CSS styling for array

Tags: css, arrays, netbeans

How would i use css to style this array? my css that I am using right now is not working, I am using a separate style sheet.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEt9p.png)

Comment: Can you share the relevant CSS code that isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming, you want to stylize not the array but the html list of items, which you are creating using the array.
You can do it (stylisation) just adding to your css file next rule

```
li {
    // your css properties go here
}
```

If you have more than one list on the page and you want add some styles only for this list, you can add some class name to the list you are creating by this php code. To do so you can change the code inside foreach statment:

```
foreach () {
    print "<li class='my-list'>";
    ...
}
```

Then you might add to css next rule wich will apply only to this specific list

```
li.my-list {
    // your css properties go here
}
```